# How to determine if the current page is a search results page?

Tags: 7, search

How can I determine from within a module or theme if the current page is an Apache solr search results page?

Comment: Which way are you trying to identify it?  From within code?

Comment: Are you referring to a Google search result (from an external site)? Or are you referring to a Drupal search result (from an internal search)? And what is the context (block, module, template, etc) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to determine from a module then you can check if the page is the search results page via the path arguments using the arg() function.

```
if (arg(0) == 'search') {
  TRUE
}
else {
  FALSE
}
```

Comment: This is what I have used before. It worked pretty well.

Comment: You might have to test for an arg(1) as well to ensure it is actually a 'results' page and not the search landing page

Comment: this only works if you are using the standard paths.

Comment: What Jeremy said, for starters... but you should be able to check for whatever paths you're using :-)   Now, you might also want to check to see if there's a third arg (arg(2)) present, which means you're on a search result page...

Answer (score 2):

From a theming point of view you could simply use

```
<?php if ($search_results) : ?>
    <!-- Do this on search results pages -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

`$search_results` should only return true if you are on a search results page.

If you're looking into styling the results themselves you might want to look into [search-result.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search-result.tpl.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find if solr has been searched you can use the [apachesolr_has_searched()](http://api.freestylesystems.co.uk/api/drupal/contributions--apachesolr--apachesolr.module/function/apachesolr_has_searched/6) function.

This won't indicate if you are on a search results page, as once you start using solr views the definition of a search results page is fuzzy, but it can tell you if a solr search has been performed.

Just for reference [apachesolr_static_response_cache()](http://api.freestylesystems.co.uk/api/drupal/contributions--apachesolr--apachesolr.module/function/apachesolr_static_response_cache/6) will give you solrs' response, and [apachesolr_current_query()](http://api.freestylesystems.co.uk/api/drupal/contributions--apachesolr--apachesolr.module/function/apachesolr_current_query/6) will give you information on the query.

Answer (score 0):

To verify if a page is a search page, you should verify the first path element of the current URL is `search`, and the second path element is the name of a module that implements `hook_search()`. (I used a temporary variable, and added extra parentheses just to be make the code more readable.)

```
$bool = ((arg(0) == 'search') &&
  ($module == arg(1)) && module_invoke($module, 'search', 'name')
);
if ($bool) {
  // The page is a search page returned from apachesolr.module.
}
```

In the specific case, considering that you want to verify if a page is a result page returned from apachesolr.module, the code can be simplified as follows:

```
if ((arg(0) == 'search') && (arg(1) == 'apachesolr')) {
  // The page is a search page returned from apachesolr.module.
}
```

The reason the generic code can be simplified is that you know the name of the module, and that module surely implements `hook_search()`.
The generic code verify the value returned by `hook_search()` when the last parameter is equal to `"name"` because there are modules that implement `hook_search()` only partially. At least that what I discovered when I was debugging the code of OpenSearch Feed.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are talking about a theme or module you could check the current URL/path if it begins with "search".

Comment: Funny how my answer is downvoted without an explaining comment, while other answers with the same solution are upvoted...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because of the lack of a code sample or something more substantive :-/